# Find the $n$-th roots of $z^n +2=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the complex equation $z^n +2=0$, in terms of $e$, so my first approach is using De Moivre's formula:

$z^n +2=0$

$z^n=-2$

$z=-2^{1/n}$,

But I don't know how to express it for put them in the unit circle.

Thanks

Comment: $[z=-2^{1/n}\text{ solves the equation }z^n=-2]\equiv\text{Ouch!}$

Answer (score 2):

$z^n=2e^{i\pi}$

$z=2^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{i\frac{2k\pi+\pi}{n}}$, $k=0,1,\cdots, n-1$.

Comment: How can I express $2^{1/n}$?

Comment: $2^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is the real number such that its $n$th power is equal to $n$.  We may use a calculator to find its approximate value.  If we want to give the exact value, we should leave it as $2^{\frac{1}{n}}$.